# Getting ClientID, Client secret, subdomain, and other endpoint details (in marketing cloud)

Tags: marketing-cloud, client-id

We are a marketing cloud ISV. We are in the process of creating our first app for marketing cloud. We wanted to know that when we list the app on appExchange and some client/organisation/marketer installs our app then how are we going to get the clientID, client secret, subdomain, wsdl file, other endpoints (soap, rest, authentication etc) pertaining to that marketing cloud account.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per [this documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/integration-considerations.htm) you should use a single credential set:

> **AppExchange Partners: Use the Same Client ID and Client Secret**
>
> Multi-tenant AppExchange apps use the same client ID and client secret
>   for all of their customers. Marketing Cloud automatically enables this
>   as part of the AppExchange app publishing and installation process.

More details on the authorisation itself can also be found in this thread: [OAuth Authorization Flow for AppExchange Packages](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/274952/oauth-authorization-flow-for-appexchange-packages)

Comment: I understood that we will be using the same ClientID and client secret which is generated at the time of developing, but how will we get the subdomian of the customer's account to initiate authorization flow.

Comment: Your application receives the customer’s Marketing Cloud subdomain, or tssd, and an authorization code after the customer has authorized your application by logging in to Marketing Cloud, as part of the authorization code grant type for web app integrations.

Comment: So just to clarify, initial authorization code request will be made by using our subdomain in url, then we will receive subdomain of the customer in the response of that request, and we can then use customer's subdomain for API calls. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct