# Marketing Cloud Installed Package JWT

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, jwt, package-install

We have a package ready to be published on app exchange and wondering if the JWT secret of the package will change for the users installing our package.
The JWT is hard coded in our Package.json and used for in a custom activity for journey builder.
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Not sure which JWT you mean but if this is for requests incoming to your package, maybe this will help you: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/274952/oauth-authorization-flow-for-appexchange-packages/274969