# Salesforce Marketing Cloud Custom Application - Integrate my application in Client SFMC instance

Tags: marketing-cloud, custom

We are developing a web application that will host some dashboards/reports built on our data warehouse and intelligence platform. Application will be hosted in Azure Cloud.

As all our end clients are marketing cloud users, we would like to integrate this application in our clients marketing cloud Instance based on Marketing Cloud documentation - [Creating a Marketing Cloud Application](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/create-a-mc-app.html)

This way they can see universal data trends that can impact their data decisions, filter dashboards and insert the results of the filtered dashboard into a data extension.

Based on the documentation, the login endpoint should kick off Marketing Cloud’s OAuth 2.0 authorization code flow - [OAuth Flow](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/integration-app-auth-code.html)

Once we have the Authorization code - part of the flow is to request the access token. [Access Token.](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/access-token-app.html)

The application request to get an access token as per the documentation is

```
Host: https://YOUR_SUBDOMAIN.auth.marketingcloudapis.com POST /v2/token Content-Type: application/json  {   "grant_type": "authorization_code",   "code": "eyJhbZciOiJIUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjIiLCJ2ZXIiOiIxIiwidHlwIjoiSldUIn0.eyJhY2Nlc3NfdG9rZW4iOiJhY0tlbEVIaTdzVERNNWd5VVR1VGdsS1YiLCJjbGllbnRfaWQiOiJmaG0yd2lsb2d2ajhqNXdzcWprZmgwejUiLCJlaWQiOjEwNzcxNzA2LCJzdGFja19rZXkiOiJRQTFTMSIsInBsYXRmb3JtX3ZlcnNpb24iOjIsImNsaWVudF90eXBlIjoiU2VydmVyVG9TZXJ2ZXIifQ.Q0qyABvInOiz3PfGsTDbj1coVTTdD8A4pCZS395P3Qo.DoROxfr3CQlMVMtVd5gYERWFYWoiNWojKObHxOq_5BqR98CDSAqfExfH-mv3PFMzy0U2NntttdgZK5wTL0UejXCxxH_XlcgL5k1TWzv_K-uTlPmliK2eI0LnaR1ti-TSqG36RnfUWzZ8KlAuGlqdGv-wgJtLeQTCEqE97yuqnlppgLLOB",   "client_id": "7a8j47upktedde30uedl822p",   “client_secret: “lYkAjPxnmHP4Zarpv1U4cLf0”   "redirect_uri": "https://127.0.0.1:80/",   "scope": "email_read email_write email_send offline" }
```

Here is the issue though - Client Id and Client secret as well as subdomain is client specific that is created when they created Installed package entry in Setup. How can we make the application integration work without this information?

Is it something related to tssd that is listed in the documentation - [Integration Considerations](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/integration-considerations.html), [TSSD](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/integration-considerations.html#appexchange-partners-request-tokens-on-your-customer%E2%80%99s-behalf)

Comment: This thread might give you some hints: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/274952/36623

Comment: Thanks @LukasLunow. Will research this path and post my findings